# NetCode For GameObjects Unity: Client Rpc params null reference exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc

I don't know why this doesn't run on my other client, but I tried a lot.

The game is poker and I need help. The rpc is called on the server in a foreach which adds the ID of the player to ClientRpcParams.

The goal of this is to have an event to spawn the players cards when they are drawn by the server.

The problem is that the client rpc never makes it to my other instance of the game running, I think the issue is that the host gets an error that the highlighted line has a null reference exception, Which doesn't make sense as I can print the value passed in right before

Please Help

**Rpc**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class Server : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public static Server instance;

    private void Awake() 
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()  
    {
        instance = this;

        if (!IsServer) 
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void UpdatePlayerClientRpc(TablePlayer.TablePlayerData player, ClientRpcParams clientRpcParams = default) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Something, anything");
        var flag = false;

        // error is line below ---------------------------
        foreach (var item in clientRpcParams.Send.TargetClientIds) 
        {
            if (item == OwnerClientId) 
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (flag) 
        {
            if (AppManager.Instance.playerNetworkObject.localPlayer == null) 
            {
                AppManager.Instance.playerNetworkObject.SpawnUi();
            }
            Debug.Log(Client.Instance.TablePlayer.tablePlayerData.position);
            Client.Instance.TablePlayer.tablePlayerData = player;
            AppManager.Instance.playerNetworkObject.ShowHand();
        }
    }

    //[ClientRpc]
    //public void BroadcastPotClientRpc(Pot newPot, ClientRpcParams clientRpcParams = default) {
    //    AppManager.Instance.game.pokerManager.CurrentPot = newPot;
    //}
}
```

**Call** (note: called from non behaviour if that matters)

```
foreach (var player in Players) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CardsInHand; i++) 
    {
        var randInt = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Deck.Count);
        player.Value.Hand.Add(Deck[randInt]);
    }
    Debug.Log(player.Key);
    Server.instance.UpdatePlayerClientRpc(player.Value.tablePlayerData, new ClientRpcParams { 
                Send = new ClientRpcSendParams {
                    TargetClientIds = new ulong[] { player.Key }
                }
    });
}
```

If you have any idea on why this may be happening please let me know

Thank you!

I tried making every monobehaviour a network behaviour and that didn't work, same result and
researching why might a clientrpc not be called, I didn't find any documentation

Comment: I figured it out, setting clientRpcParams.Send.TargetClientIds automatically sends the value to the correct target, checking for it is redundant and in this case, breaks everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting clientRpcParams.Send.TargetClientIds automatically sends the value to the correct target, checking for it is redundant and in this case, breaks everything

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).